# wire:click.prevent function not working inside foreach looping

Tags: php, ajax, foreach, laravel-livewire

I making search function with ajax.
After fetch data with foreach loop , the result component did not support livewire (wire:click.prevent). Other tag that outside of the looping is working fine .

**contact-search.blade.php**

```
<div>
    <input type="text" class="form-controller" id="search" name="search"></input>
    <main>
    </main>
    <a href="#" wire:click="test">Click</a>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.13.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#search').on('keyup', function () {
            $value = $(this).val();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'get',
                url: '{{URL::to('search')}}',
                data: { 'search': $value },
                success: function (data) {
                    $('main').html(data);
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $.ajaxSetup({ headers: { 'csrftoken': '{{ csrf_token() }}' } });
    </script>
</div>
```

**SearchController.php**

```
public function search(Request $request)
{
    if($request->ajax())
    {
        $output="";
        // $users= DB::table('users')->where('name','LIKE','%'.$request->search."%")->get();
        // $users= User::where('name','LIKE','%'.$request->search."%")->get();
        $users= User::where('name',$request->search)->get();
        if($users)
        {
            foreach ($users as $key => $user) {
                $output.='<a href="#" wire:click="test" >'.
                                'click'.
                         '</a>';
            }
            return Response($output);
        }
    }   
}
```

**ContactSearch.php**

```
public function test()
{
    dd('HEllo');
}
```

**web.php**

```
Route::get('/search',[SearchController::class,'search'])->name('search');
```

Answer (score 1):

Livewire is serverside. Implementing a client side request means that the server is already done loading. At this point, Livewire will no longer check if it needs to bind anything. Also, Livewire is designed to perform client-to-server requests and vice versa, so using `$.ajax` with Livewire is totally not adviced. I really advice reading the [docs](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/quickstart) on how to get started with Livewire.

Answer (score 0):

I making search function with ajax.
After fetch data with foreach loop , the result component did not support livewire (wire:click.prevent). One of the tag that outside of the looping is working fine .
I need solution pls help .